# Why does the same bitwise calculation yield different results in Java and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, translate, crc16

**Problem:**

I need to calculate a **CRC16** for hex codes like this one:

`08010000016B40D8EA30010000000000000000000000000000000105021503010101425E0F01F10000601A014E000000000000000001`

For this, I have a working solution in **JavaScript**. Due to new requirements, I have to translate this code into **Java**.

**Expected result:**

For above hex string: `0000C7CF` *( 51151 )*.

**My approach:**

I have the following, working **JavaScript** code, which I am trying to translate into **Java**:

```js
var hex = "08010000016B40D8EA30010000000000000000000000000000000105021503010101425E0F01F10000601A014E000000000000000001";

var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2){ 
  str += String.fromCharCode( parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16) );
}

var crc = 0x0000;
var poly = 0xA001;

for (var pos = 0; pos < str.length; pos++) {
  crc ^= str.charCodeAt(pos);
  for (var i = 8; i !== 0; i--) {
    if ((crc & 0x0001) !== 0) {
      crc >>= 1;
      crc ^= poly;
    } else
      crc >>= 1;
  }
}
console.log( crc ); // 51151
console.log( crc.toString(16) ); // c7cf
```

My current implementation in Java looks like this:

```java
String hex = "08010000016B40D8EA30010000000000000000000000000000000105021503010101425E0F01F10000601A014E000000000000000001";
byte[] arr = Hex.decodeHex( hex );
long polynomial = 0xA001;
long crc = 0x0000;
for (byte b : arr) {
    crc ^= b;
    for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--) {
        if ((crc & 0x01) != 0) {
            crc >>= 1;
            crc ^= polynomial;
        } else {
            crc >>= 1;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println( crc ); // -37776
```

As you can see, the translated Java code does not calculate the expected result.

**Question:**

Why does this code yield different results in **Java** and **JavaScript**?

Comment: Your JS version is doing `if ((crc & 0x0001) !== 0) {` whilst your Java version does `if ((crc & 0x01) != 0) {` (first line inside the for loop) maybe thats causing issues? All other values are similar so i suppose that should be similar too?

Comment: The `!=` in java is equivalent to `!==` in Javascript.

Comment: I wanted to point out that the numbers youre using in the binary-anding are different (`crc & 0x0001` vs `crc & 0x01`) not the operators actually.

Comment: Isn't `0x01` and `0x0001` just 1 ? Anyways, the result for either `0x01` or `0x0001` or even just `1`. Is the same (in both Java and JS)

Comment: Do you know at which time the output becomes different? If not, you can try to output it at each iteration and then check at which iteration the JS and Java version are not equal (e.g. you can compare it with git or an online diff tool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the following line from

`crc ^= b`

to

`crc ^= (b & 0xff)`

In java, `byte` ranges from -128 to 127, so you have to make it unsigned.